# What are the default gems of Mac OSX 10.11?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I tried to study Ruby on Rails and followed a tutorial. However, I think I missed a part and I can't proceed to the next step in the tutorial, so I plan to uninstall things, including the gems I installed, and start all over again.

I installed Ruby using Homebrew, because people say it's best not to mess with the Ruby that comes with macOS. Then, I uninstalled it again using `brew uninstall ruby`.

After doing that, I ran `gem list` and this came out:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

- bigdecimal (1.2.0)
- builder (3.2.2)
- CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
- io-console (0.4.2)
- json (1.7.7)
- libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
- minitest (4.3.2)
- nokogiri (1.5.6)
- psych (2.0.0)
- rake (0.9.6)
- rdoc (4.0.0)
- sqlite3 (1.3.7)
- test-unit (2.0.0.0)
- thor (0.19.1)
```

What are the gems (if any) that come with macOS system Ruby?

Answer (score 6):

My fresh El Capitan gives:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.0)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.7.7)
libxml-ruby (2.6.0)
minitest (4.3.2)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
psych (2.0.0)
rake (0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
test-unit (2.0.0.0)
```

which is the same as @jsejcksn mentioned. For macOS 10.13.6 (High Sierra) and 10.14.5 (Mojave) the list is

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3.1)
libxml-ruby (2.9.0)
minitest (5.8.5)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.1.0.1)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
test-unit (3.1.5)
```

Answer (score 3):

As addendum, for anybody else wondering what the current default Gems on `macOS 10.13.3` are:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.8)
CFPropertyList (2.2.8)
did_you_mean (1.0.0)
io-console (0.4.5)
json (1.8.3)
libxml-ruby (2.9.0)
minitest (5.8.5)
net-telnet (0.1.1)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
power_assert (0.2.6)
psych (2.1.0)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
test-unit (3.1.5)
```

Shipped gem version is `2.5.2`.

Answer (score 3):

#### macOS 12.0.1 Monterey

```
% gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (default: 1.4.1)
bundler (default: 1.17.2)
CFPropertyList (2.3.6)
cmath (default: 1.0.0)
csv (default: 3.0.9)
date (default: 2.0.0)
dbm (default: 1.0.0)
did_you_mean (1.3.0)
e2mmap (default: 0.1.0)
etc (default: 1.0.1)
fcntl (default: 1.0.0)
fiddle (default: 1.0.0)
fileutils (default: 1.1.0)
forwardable (default: 1.2.0)
io-console (default: 0.4.7)
ipaddr (default: 1.2.2)
irb (default: 1.0.0)
json (default: 2.1.0)
libxml-ruby (3.2.1)
logger (default: 1.3.0)
matrix (default: 0.1.0)
mini_portile2 (2.4.0)
minitest (5.11.3)
mutex_m (default: 0.1.0)
net-telnet (0.2.0)
nokogiri (1.10.1)
openssl (default: 2.1.2)
ostruct (default: 0.1.0)
power_assert (1.1.3)
prime (default: 0.1.0)
psych (default: 3.1.0)
rake (12.3.3)
rdoc (default: 6.1.2.1)
rexml (default: 3.1.9.1)
rss (default: 0.2.7)
scanf (default: 1.0.0)
sdbm (default: 1.0.0)
shell (default: 0.7)
sqlite3 (1.3.13)
stringio (default: 0.0.2)
strscan (default: 1.0.0)
sync (default: 0.5.0)
test-unit (3.2.9)
thwait (default: 0.1.0)
tracer (default: 0.1.0)
webrick (default: 1.4.4)
xmlrpc (0.3.0)
zlib (default: 1.0.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

OS X 10.10 has Ruby 2.0 has the default version, so I guess 10.11 is the same.

However, I would suggest you to use Ruby 2.3.0, because it is the most current stable version.

Since you are using brew, you can use the following code:-

```
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

# Install Ruby
rbenv install 2.3.0
rbenv global 2.3.0
ruby -v
```

Reference: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.11-el-capitan

UPDATE: latest stable should be 2.3.0 instead of 2.2.3. Thanks spikermann for pointing out.

Comment: Ruby 2.3.0 was released [last Christmas](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/). Why to you consider Ruby 2.3.0 to be unstable?

Comment: @JeffersonChoi Thanks! Yeah, my mac's built in ruby is version 2.0.0. But im not sure if the gems i listed above is also the default gems for the built in ruby version. Hopefully I did not delete a gem for the built in ruby version..

Comment: To be frank, I don't think this answers the question; it is more of a comment.